# Dropdown code for All countries with their respective state and cities with Zip Code

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

I want to include country, city, state, and zip code for some e-commerce site and I want it as if I select specific country cities of that specific country only is listed. once the city is selected states of that city is seen in the drop-down and once a city is selected zip code for that.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two very different languages. Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: there are lots of build-in codes you can find out an try I don't think this question is good for here 
https://phppot.com/php/country-state-city-example-cascading-jquery-dependent-dropdown/